# auto print using jquery

Tags: jquery, printing, datagridview, datatables

I have the data in the following format:

**(Dummy Entries)(id=posGridView)**

[image]

As I process the sale, a small receipt print automatically with selected columns, not all the columns.

Because all data is available in this grid view, How can I print it dynamically with any format with jquery?

**Edited**

Actually I want to print in this format dynamically from the above grid view

[image]

Comment: whats dynamically means?

Comment: @BothFM. That's easy: _"Computers . (of data storage, processing, or programming) affected by the passage of time or the presence or absence of power: Dynamic memory must be constantly refreshed to avoid losing data. Dynamic Web sites contain Web pages that are generated in real time."_ `LOL`

Comment: dynamically means real time ;) @BothFM

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**Printing**

There's no need for jQuery for printing a page, you just need the JavaScript function: `window.print();`.

If you need to print an specific content, you can hide the rest (and format the printed area) by CSS:

```
<style media="screen">
  .noPrint{ display: block; }
  .yesPrint{ display: block !important; }
</style> 
<style media="print">
  .noPrint{ display: none; }
  .yesPrint{ display: block !important; }
</style>
```

As you can see, by setting the *media* attribute of your style tag, you can set up styles for both the normal view (screen) and the printing view (print). Full article is [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13246/Print-a-doument-with-CSS).

**Dynamism**

You can add certain dynamism to the process, but keep in mind that it can be *dinamically* for the user, but in your code **you'll have to find and *event* to attach the printing**. That event could be a click in an anchor:

`<a href='javascript:window.print();'>Print</a>`

It could be the *onload* event of your page:

```
window.onload = function () {
    window.print();
}
```

Or any other event that you might need to be aware (notice that now I'm using jQuery):

```
var doPrintPage;

function printPage(){
    window.print();
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input').blur(function(){
        //3sec after the user leaves the input, printPage will fire
        doPrintPage = setTimeout('printPage();', 3000);
    });
    $('input').focus(function(){
        //But if another input gains focus printPage won't fire
        clearTimeout(doPrintPage);
    });
});
```

The code above is pretty straight-forward: after three seconds of the user leaving an input, *printPage* will fire. If an input get the focus in those three seconds, *printPage* won't be called. I don't really think this precise code is what you need, but I'll make the point how to emulate *dynamism*. Here can see the [setTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) and [clearTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_cleartimeout.asp) definitions.

**EDIT: I hardly suggest you to hide your unwanted-to-print html through CSS as explained above and call *window.print***. Anyway, here I'm adding some code for doing it through a new page.

**Printing from a brand new page**

If you want to print *from* a totally different page that the one you're showing, you can ask for that page, manage the html in your server-side and then tell the page to print as soon as get loaded. There's at least two ways to do this. Let see them step by step:

A) The first choice is to send your GridView to your new page and print it from there. The problem is that you can't easily open a new page to do this, so you'll have to browse from your page to a new one showing your html-to-print.

A1) For this, you need to surround your GridView with a form:

```
<form runat="server">
<asp:GridView id="gridView" />
<asp:Button id="btnPrint" Text="Print" runat="server" OnClick="btnPrint_Click" />
</form>
```

A2) Then from *btnPrint_Click* you'll call your "printPage.aspx". Remember that if you changed your GridView with JS/jQuery, those changes could be not available (since it's likely that .NET reads a hidden state variable rather than your GridView).

B) The second way to do it is through JavaScript. But remember that with this choice you'll have a hard time if you want to edit your table in your new page (because you won't be receiving a GridView, you'll receiving html). The good thing is that you can easily open a new page:

B1) Off course, you'll need a form (notice its target and action), something like:

```
<form id="myPageForm" name="myPageForm" target="_blank" action="printPage.aspx">
    <input type="hidden" name="htmlToPrint" id="htmlToPrint" />
    <input type="button" value="submit">Print</button>
</form>
```

B2) Then you'll have to pass your data to that anchor. Before submitting the form, set the input with your table data:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myPageForm').submit(function(){
        //Filling the hidden input
        var htmlToPrint = $(".posGridView").html(); //I'm using a class and not an ID 'cause .NET will change your GridView's ID when rendering you page
        $("#htmlToPrint").value(htmlToPrint);
        return true;
    });
});
```

Once you have the data in your server side (printPage.asx), you can easily create your HTML-to-print and call window.print() on that page *onload*, as described above.

Comment: Dear, this is you telling me how to print.But I have problem that I have a Grid view and I want to print receipt in specific format dynamically, mean rum time I want to create the receipt that print my receipt in my desire format . please see my update post! @Ale

Comment: OK Dear, But I am using Java. You explain very well.

Comment: Can window.print() be used to print elements below scroll bar? ie. If there is an overflow?

Comment: @SauravDangol browsers will tend to print your content _as is_. What you want to do in this case is to add some only-printing CSS (see answer on how) to make the overflow visible, as in _height: auto; overflow: visible_.